# A more efficient way of performing a multiple price changes function

Tags: excel, vba

I've been wondering if there is a more efficient, and probably neater way of performing an amateur function that I've just coded:

```
Public Function JanApr_prices()

'catalogue price changes
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1)
.DataBodyRange(44, 4).Value = 4.8 'Product A
.DataBodyRange(52, 4).Value = 4.5 'Product B
.DataBodyRange(77, 4).Value = 6 'Product C
.DataBodyRange(79, 4).Value = 9 'Product D
End With

End function
```

This basically changes prices for a set number of months when I'm doing some accounting. While it works, it definitely has its drawbacks because if I ever changed the relative position of the entries on the table, the price changes would probably go to the wrong place. So I'm in need of another idea, perhaps using a combination of `.cells` and `match`? I like to do things neatly and all the solutions that I've thought up so far are rather ponderous. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Feel free to edit the post title, I really did not know how to describe my problem!

Comment: A picture of the layout would help.  Your idea to use `Match` is a good one.  You just need to determine what text to find in order to make the match.  We really can't help based on what you've provided though.  You could also iterate through cells using `For` or `For Each` and search for a given condition... or use `Find` to look for specific text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is not complete and will have to be adjusted to your needs. It is merely ment to show you the basic concept of the solution I propose.

```
Public Function JanApr_prices()
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim lCount As Long

vArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1).Range.Value2

For lCount = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    Select Case vArr(lCount, 1)
    Case "Produkt A"
        vArr(lCount, 2) = 4.8
    Case "Produkt B"
        vArr(lCount, 2) = 4.5
    Case "Produkt C"
        vArr(lCount, 2) = 6
    Case "Produkt D"
        vArr(lCount, 2) = 9
    End Select
Next lCount

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1).Range.Value2 = vArr

End Function
```

The above code was taken from this website and slightly adapted:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/

While I do not like to copy code from the web, StackOverflow prefers to be self-contained without the need to external references. So, there you go.

Comment: Sorry I took a little longer than normal to reply, was reading up on arrays, lbound ubounds and how they worked. This is such a brilliant method! I understand value2 is usually faster but I'm wondering if there is a smart way to return to the original formatting without sacrificing on the speed?

Comment: @lackdaz: You just described the difference between `.Value` and `.Value2`. So, no, there is no other way. If you need the cell content to be evaluated then you need `.Value`. But remember that the formatting is within the sheet *only*. If you format a cell, take a number from that cell and place another number in that cell then you did not change the formatting and the cell will be still formatted the same way the original number was formatted.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you further. You really brought my understanding of arrays from nothing to somewhere